# How to get which node invoked getter function?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Is it possible to get which node/object has invoked the setter function?

**why am I asking this?**

atm I have custom animation player:

```
tool
extends Animation

func track_insert_key(track_idx : int, time : float, key, transition : float = 1) -> void:
    var track_path=track_get_path(track_idx)
    var key_node=<some_function>.get_node(track_path)
    
    if(key_node.get_class()=="some_node"):
         # do something before setting keyframe

    .track_insert_key(track_idx, time, key, transition)
```

but I can eliminate the need of a custom animation player if I could intercept who called
the getter function, maybe something like this:

```
tool
extends Node2D

var custom_variable=0 setget ,get_custom_variable

func get_custom_variable(by):
    print("called by=",by)
    if(by.get_class()=="Animation"):
       # do something before setting keyframe
```

so is anything like this possible? or some similar approach which eliminates the need of a custom `AnimationPlayer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS ANSWER DOES NOT WORK ON TOOL SCRIPTS RUNNING ON THE EDITOR**

---

We cannot exactly get the calling `Node`, but we can have an idea of the caller.

We can get an iterate over the stack trace like this:

```
var stack := get_stack()
for item in stack:
    prints(item)
```

The [`get_strack`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_%40gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-get-stack) function returns an `Array` that contains a `Dictionary` per entry of the call stack, with these keys:

- `"function"`: The name of the calling method.
- `"line"`: The line number of the call.
- `"source"`: The path of the calling script.

So, no, we are not getting the instance that is calling.

By the way, the first entry (index `0`) returned by `get_stack` corresponds to the call to `get_stack`. So you want the second entry (index `1`). Furthermore, the result will only have one entry if your script is not being called from a script (e.g. the engine is calling a method such as `_ready` or `_process`, or it is resuming from `yield`):

```
var stack := get_stack()
var path_of_the_script := ""
if stack.size() == 1:
    prints("called from external code")
else:
    path_of_the_script = stack[1].source
```

Beyond that, we could look into `ProjectSettings.get_setting("_global_script_classes")` to find out the name of the class (if it is an script with `class_name`):

```
var stack := get_stack()
var path_of_the_script := ""
if stack.size() == 1:
    prints("called from external code")
else:
    path_of_the_script = stack[1].source
    var class_id := path_of_the_script
    if ProjectSettings.has_setting("_global_script_classes"):
        for x in ProjectSettings.get_setting("_global_script_classes"):
            if x.path == path_of_the_script:
                class_id = x.class

    prints("called from:", class_id)
```

And that would be the name of the script class that is calling your method, if it has one. Hopefully that is useful enough.

Comment: I haven't tested this with a `tool` script. I hope it is not an issue. Also probably just checking the size of `get_stack` is enough to discriminate for the use case at hand.

Comment: I tried [this](https://pastecode.io/s/ti388kc3) but it's giving an empty array when invoking `get_stack()`

Comment: @arsher Tested. And yes, it gives an empty `Array`. But similar code without `tool` works. I have to conclude it does not work with `tool` scripts. My best guess is that it is disabled in editor builds.